# Manage wrapped C++ vs native C++ - socket call differences

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a version of all native (C++) code that compiles to communicate over TCP and thus utilizing socket/connect.  This is compiled in Visual Studio 2010 and produces a basic command line executable.  When I step through the code for making a socket connection, all works great.  And further noting, the full TCP communications look good and do what I want.

Then in my C# version (VS 2010 as well) of code to make a GUI version of the above native code, I run into some issues.  The same "connection" library used in the native code above is wrapped to make a managed DLL library to access general native connection library calls.  The C# program works fine, but when I step through the code and get to the Winsock2 socket call, a socket is not attained and simply -1 is returned.  I cannot step into the 'socket' call and thus at a loss for why the two programs operate differently.  Once the code is into the native code, I would assume that library to operate that same here (C# program) as it did for the native specific code.

```
m_sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I have stepped through both programs where the native code attains the socket, but the C# version does not.  Why would one version work and the other not?

Comment: May be it got garbage collected?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Why would a simple call of 'socket' (Winsock2) get garbage collected?  Wouldn't it defeat the purpose of my DLL wrappered native code if all items such as this gets garbage collected?  I might expect this at the wrapper DLL level, but not down in the native library code.

Comment: You have a very nasty bug in your code, it is clearly visible in the snippet.  It has very inadequate error reporting.  So bad that simple failure of a C function is completely undiagnosable.  Only you can fix that.  I'll put a buck on WSANOTINITIALIZED, any takers?

Comment: Yes, you are most likely correct.  I am so used to native code, or non-windows code, not having to do a WSA startup.  I was forgetting that the original program for the C# program is Windows based.  Once I update some error handling, I will respond again and hopefully close this out.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Per the response of Hans Passant, it is true that the issue at hand is the WSA Startup missing prior to attaining the socket.  And it is also true that the WSAGetLastError will provide an insightful error code to state that the WSA was not initilized.  Consider it solved.

It was forgotten that when running from a Windows platform, that WSA needs started prior to usage socket usage.  This is not the case when running regular C++ native code.